# Codeigniter Session variables, forms, updating database values

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have been working on a form where I retrieve all details of a user and fill them into the textfields in the form. I have a session running but the values from the textfields I am calling them directly from the database and posting them to my view

**View**

```
<?php
                                foreach ($getrecord as $key => $getdetails)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?= $getdetails['s_county']?>"> <?php } ?>
```

**Model**

```
 public function getstudent($getstudent)
  {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('qcs_student');
    $this->db->where('student_id', $getstudent);
    $query= $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function myprofile()
  {
    $mydata = $this->session->all_userdata();
    $getstudent = $mydata['student_id'];

    $data['getrecord'] = $this->model_student->getstudent($getstudent);

        $this->load->view('student/header', array('logged_in'=>$this->logged_in));
        $this->load->view('student/myprofile', $data, array('logged_in' => $this->logged_in));
        $this->load->view('student/footer');

}
```

Now the issue arises after updating users details `s_username` from the textifield, it saves changes to the database but the textfield value does not change, even if i change the same username over 10 times, when I reload the page with the view, same story, the textfield is populated by the same same value and not the updated value from the database.

Strange it is, I have cross-checked my code, still nothing to edit, coz all seems fine, but the textfield still shows the same value, instead of refreshing and displating the latest updated `s_username` from my db

Comment: Check once may be you have enable caching in CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
value="<?php echo set_value('s_county')
```